# Seg fault when passing python object into class wrapped with Cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I used Cython to wrap a number of C++ classes and they managed to compile. However, when I tried to use the python level modules, I encountered segmentation fault (11), so I was wondering what I was wrapping is right. A in "Foo.h" is an abstract class.

source.pyx

```
cdef extern from "Foo.h":
   cdef cppclass A:
      A(MPI_comm comm, int x)
cdef extern from "Foo1.h":
   cdef cppclass B:
      B(A* obj, int y)

cdef class pyA:
   cdef A *thisptrA
   def __cinit__(self,MPI.Comm _comm, int x):
      pass
   def __dealloc__(self):
      pass
cdef class pyB:
   cdef B* thisptrB
   cdef pyA obj
   def __cinit__(self, pyA obj, int y):
      self.thisptrB = new B(obj.thisptrA, y) 
   def __dealloc__(self):
      del self.thisptrB
```

testscript.py

```
import pyA, pyB
class C(pyA):
   def __init__(self, comm, x):
      self.x = x

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
x = 2
y = 24
Aobj = C(comm, x)

Bobj = pyB(Aobj, y)
```

It seems that whenever I tried initializing pyB, a segmentation fault occurs at the statement

```
self.thisptrB = newB(obj.thisptrA, y)
```

Does anyone have any idea where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You don't look to ever being assigning `thisptrA` in `pyA`. Therefore the thing it's pointing to is either null or random (I'm not sure which for Cython).

Exactly what's causing the segmentation fault is probably hidden in the constructor for `B`, which you don't short us.

One further thing you may want to think about: you likely want to make sure that the lifetime for the `A` exceeds the lifetime for the `B` that (I assume) holds a pointer to it. One way of doing that would be to keep a reference to the `PyA` within your `PyB` (i.e. within `__init__` for `PyB` put `self._held_A = obj`)